# If $f(a),f(f(a)),...$ has exactly one limit point, then it converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be  continuous. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the sequence $f(a),f(f(a)),...$ has exactly one limit point.  Show that this sequence converges.

I first showed that a bounded sequence which has exactly one limit point necessarily converges. So we might start by supposing that the sequence is unbounded. I am not sure how to exploit the continuity of $f$ though, except for the obvious fact that any limit point is a fixed point.

Comment: I have demonstrated that if a bounded sequence has exactly one limit point, then it converges.

Comment: @diophantineman For future reference, that's the kind of context you should provide along with your question statement.

Comment: ok edited sorry im new to the site

Comment: @diophantineman no problem. And welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Corrected** HINT: Let $f^1(x)=f(x)$ and $f^{n+1}(x)=f\left(f^n(x)\right)$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, and for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $a_n=f^n(a)$. Let $b$ be the unique cluster point of $\sigma=\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$.

For $\epsilon>0$ let $M_\epsilon=\{n\in\Bbb Z^+:|a_n-b|\ge\epsilon\}$.

- Show that $\{n\in M_\epsilon:|a_n-b|\le\ell\}$ is finite for each $\ell\in\Bbb Z^+$.
- Use the continuity of $f$ to show that there are an $\epsilon>0$ and an $\ell\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $|a_{n+1}-b|\le\ell$ whenever $n\in\Bbb Z^+\setminus M_\epsilon$.
- Deduce that $M_\epsilon$ is finite for each $\epsilon>0$ and hence that $\sigma$ converges to $b$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your line of thinking. The first bullet is obvious The third bullet as well, for if $a_\phi(n)$ is a subsequence converging to $b$ then $a_{\phi(n)+1}=f(a_\phi(n))$ converges to $f(b)$ by continuity (so $f(b)=b$ and thus $a_{\phi(n)+1}$ converges to $b$. This of course implies of $n$ sufficiently large, $|a_{\phi(n)+1}|<|b|+1$.

Comment: Assuming the second bullet is true, by choosing $l>|b|+1$, we are forced to conclude that for $n$ sufficiently large, $\phi(n)+1$ is in $M$. In other words, for $m$ sufficiently large $m \in M$ implies $m+1 \in M$.

Comment: This would imply that $M$ is of the form $\{n in N : n \ge m_0\}$ for some $m_0$, which would resolve the problem. However, I fail to see why the second bullet should be true.

Comment: @diophantineman: You’re right: I was carelessly thinking that $M$ was in some sense maximal. Let me think about it for a bit and either fix or delete it.

Comment: That's what I thought you were thinking, that $M$ was sort of maximal (if it was "maximal" and its complement was bounded, then Bolzano gives us a contradiction). But in fact I don't think in any precise sense we can choose $M$ maximal s.t the sequence ${u_n : n \in M}$ converges to $b$, for we could always add elements to this set one at a time whilst keeping the convergence.

Comment: @diophantineman: You’re quite right that there’s no way to pick a maximal $M$; fortunately, there’s a way around the problem.

Comment: your work-around is rather subtle I have to say. I think we can make it simpler and more clear by choosing $l=1$, and then showing that for all $\epsilon$ sufficiently small (small enough so that $|x-b|<\epsilon$ implies $f(x)-f(b)$<1, $M_\epsilon$ is finite.